# Parents of Dhaumya

Tags: scripture, mahabharata

A Gandharva suggests Arjuna to appoint Dhaumya as (purohit)priest

> "The Gandharva replied, 'There is in these woods a shrine of the name
> of Utkochaka. Dhaumya, the younger brother of Devala is engaged there
> in ascetic penances. Appoint him, if ye desire, your priest."
>
> [[Section 185, Chaitraratha Parva, Adi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01186.htm)

And the pandavas do the same. And during agnathavasa, Dhaumya guided them a lot. He can be considered as an important person in pandavas lives.

Does the Mahabharata mention the names of his parents? If no, then do any scriptures mention them?

Answer (score 2):

Dhaumya is famously known as the purohita of the Pāṇḍavas (Ādi Parva 182.2, etc.). Tracing the parents of Dhaumya is a difficult task (which may not yield a certain solution), and there would be a series of deductions involved, because we don't have a direct answer in the śāstras regarding this. I will break down the question into different topics, so as to ease the difficulty.

**Dhaumya's gotra & his brothers**

1. As per Ādi Parva (182.2), Pāṇḍava purohita Dhaumya is the younger brother of Devala. (*yavīyān devalasyaiṣa vane bhrātā tapasyati*)
2. As per Kaśyapa gotra-pravara list of Baudhāyana śrautasūtras in Puruṣottama Paṇḍita's [Gotrapravaramañjari](https://archive.org/details/earlybrahmanicalsystemsofgotraanpravaragotrapravaramanjariofpurshottamajohnbroughoup_202003_875_K/page/n87/mode/2up), Dhaumya belongs to Kaśyapa gotra.
3. As per Anuśāsana Parva (14.111-112), Liṅga Purāṇa ([1.107.32](https://archive.org/details/LingaMahaPuranaByDwarikaPrasadMishraShastriChowkhambaSanskritSeries/page/n635/mode/2up?view=theater)), Śiva Purāṇa ([7.1.34.1](https://archive.org/details/SzWh_shiv-mahapuran-of-veda-vyas-chapter-2-second-half-with-hindi-vyakhya-illustration-gita-press/page/n881/mode/2up?view=theater)),..etc. , Dhaumya is the younger brother of Ṛṣi Upamanyu Vāsiṣṭha, son of Ṛṣi Vyāghrapāda Vāsiṣṭha. Therefore, Dhaumya is a Vāsiṣṭha (i.e. belongs to Vasiṣṭha gotra), and his father is Ṛṣi Vyāghrapāda Vāsiṣṭha. But in these references, it's not specified that Dhaumya (brother of Upamanyu) is the same Dhaumya, who was purohita of Pāṇḍavas.

**Is Pāṇḍava purohita Dhaumya, younger brother of Devala or Upamanyu ?**

As stated above, Dhaumya is said to be the younger brother of both Devala & Upamanyu Vāsiṣṭha.  There are two possible resolutions to this situation-

1. Devala is the real brother of Pāṇdava purohita Dhaumya, and Upamanyu is not Dhaumya's actual blood brother. But Upamanyu and Dhaumya might share a brotherly relationship, such as Dhaumya being an adopted brother of Upamanyu, or Upamanyu being a cousin brother of Dhaumya from mother's side, or Upamanyu being a brother disciple.
2. There are two unique Dhaumyas, one being Vāsiṣṭha and another Kāśyapa. But Pāṇḍava purohita Dhaumya is Kāśyapa, and real brother of Devala.

In both of these resolutions, we are taking Pāṇḍava purohita Dhaumya to be a Kāśyapa, and Devala (and not Upamanyu Vāsiṣṭha) to be his real elder brother , as the earlier section, leaves no doubt on Dhaumya's gotra being Kaśyapa and Devala being his elder brother.

Since, I am not able to find any direct reference from Mahāpurāṇas, which reveal the parents of Dhaumya, so we would need to check the parentage of his elder brother Devala.

**Gotra of Dhaumya's brother Devala**

As per Kaśyapa gotra-pravara lists in [Gotrapravaramañjari](https://archive.org/details/earlybrahmanicalsystemsofgotraanpravaragotrapravaramanjariofpurshottamajohnbroughoup_202003_875_K/page/n87/mode/2up) and Brahmāṇḍa Purāṇa ([1.32.112-114](https://archive.org/details/BrahmandaMahapuranEdByDr.KVSharmaKrishnaDasAcademy/page/n215/mode/2up?view=theater)), Devala belongs to Kaśyapa gotra. But Brahmāṇda Purāṇa ([3.66.72](https://archive.org/details/BrahmandaMahapuranEdByDr.KVSharmaKrishnaDasAcademy/page/n475/mode/2up?view=theater)) & Vāyu Purāṇa ([91.100](https://archive.org/details/wg1194/page/n839/mode/2up?view=theater)) mention Devala's gotra to be Viśvāmitra. But Dhaumya Kāśyapa's elder brother would be a Kāśyapa too, so there's no point in taking Dhaumya's brother to be a Vaiśvāmitra here. Also, majority of gotra-pravara lists mention Devala to be a Kāśyapa.

**Parents of Devala Kāśyapa**

Devala's parentage is extremely varied. In other words, there are many Devalas in śāstras. But here,  we're only concerned with a Brāhmaṇa named Devala, who was Kāśyapa. And there's one such Devala among [7 persons named Devala in śāstras](https://archive.org/details/devala-smriti-1-m.-l.-wadekar/page/n53/mode/2up?view=theater), who is the son of Asita. As per Vāyu Purāṇa ([70.24-25](https://archive.org/details/wg1194/page/n663/mode/2up?view=theater)), Kaśyapa had two sons - Vatsāra and Asita, and Asita had a great son named Devala alongwith his wife Ekaparṇā. (Vāyu Purāṇa [72.17](https://archive.org/details/wg1194/page/n683/mode/2up?view=theater) ; Brahmāṇḍa Purāṇa [2.10.18-19](https://archive.org/details/BrahmandaMahapuranEdByDr.KVSharmaKrishnaDasAcademy/page/n303/mode/2up?view=theater)).

**Parents of Dhaumya Kāśyapa**

As per the earlier cited Kaśyapa gotra-pravara list of Baudhāyana śrautasūtras in Puruṣottama Paṇḍita's [Gotrapravaramañjari](https://archive.org/details/earlybrahmanicalsystemsofgotraanpravaragotrapravaramanjariofpurshottamajohnbroughoup_202003_875_K/page/n87/mode/2up), Dhaumya belongs to Kaśyapa gotra. And, he has a tryārṣeya pravara (such as 'Kāśyapa, Āvatsāra, Naidhruva'). Since, Devala is the son of Asita (brother of Vatsāra/Avatsāra), then there would be a difference of at least two generations b/w Devala and Dhaumya, as per this account.  This is because the pravara of Dhaumya, contains the ṛṣis Avatsāra (or Vatsāra) and Nidhruva (son of Vatsāra). But since, Ādi Parva (182.2) is clear in stating that Pāṇḍava purohita Dhaumya is younger brother of Devala, then there shouldn't be doubt entertained upon that. There are two resolutions-

1. The Dhaumya in gotra-pravara list is some other Ṛṣi (descended from Avatsāra), who shares the same name with Devala Kāśyapa's little brother Dhaumya
2. There's an error in the Kaśyapa gotra-pravara list regarding the pravara of Dhaumya in Gotrapravaramañjari, and that few errors crept in the gotra-pravara lists (that are preserved now) are quite probable.

If Devala Kāśyapa is elder brother & real sibling of Pāṇḍava purohita Dhaumya, then both would have the same parents. So,  parents of Pāṇḍava purohita Dhaumya would be Asita & Ekaparṇā.

Another solution would be dropping that Devala is a biological sibling of Dhaumya (but still both have a brotherly relationship), and taking Dhaumya to be younger brother of Upamanyu Vāsiṣṭha. Then, Dhaumya's father would be Ṛṣi Vyāghrapāda, as has been earlier stated. 
There's actually a great possibility for Pāṇḍava purohita Dhaumya to be Upamanyu Vāsiṣṭha's brother, for a lot of śāstras state that, some of which have been cited before in the answer. But those references don't specify that Upamanyu's brother Dhaumya was really Pāṇḍava's purohita.
In the case, Dhaumya is Upamanyu's little brother, Devala being elder brother of Dhaumya can be explained as follows- both might be cousins (not paternal), one of them might be an adopted brother, or both might be brother disciples (i.e. śiṣyas of same guru).

*Note* 
There's a Ṛṣi named Āyodadhaumya, who features in Pauṣya Parva, and he had three śiṣyas - Upamanyu, Āruṇi, & Veda. However, Āyodadhaumya and Pāṇḍava purohita Dhaumya seem different persons (even though both have the name Dhaumya), for the latter has never been addressed by the name Āyoda (possibly patronym) throughout Mahābhārata.

*The numbering of ślokas from Mahābhārata, follows Gītā Press*.